# Binding Adapter warning? Overriding one method with another

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-binding-adapter

```
Binding adapter AK(android.widget.EditText, android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener) 
already exists for onFocus! Overriding 
Java_File_1#bindFocusChange with Java_File_2#bindFocusChange
```

I am getting this warning above, guessing something related to edittext. But it shows warning in java file. Below are two #bindFocusChange methods in both the java class files.

Java_File_1:

```
@BindingAdapter("onFocus")
public static void bindFocusChange(EditText editText, View.OnFocusChangeListener onFocusChangeListener) {
    if (editText.getOnFocusChangeListener() == null) {
        editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(onFocusChangeListener);
    }
}
```

Java_File_2:

```
 @BindingAdapter("onFocus")
public static void bindFocusChange(EditText editText, View.OnFocusChangeListener
        onFocusChangeListener) {
    if (editText.getOnFocusChangeListener() == null) {
        editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(onFocusChangeListener);
    }
}
```

> P.S: The warning is Android Gradle Plugin Warning. Dont know if that can help any. But just saying

Comment: Have you found fix of this?

Comment: @rupesh somewhat, If you just rename one of them to something else, this warning goes away